# Search and replace based on a dictionary

Tags: json, vim

I have a json file filled with a list of data where each element has one field called url.

```
[
  { ...,
    ...,
    "url": "us.test.com"
  },
  ...
]
```

In a different file I have a list of mappings that I need to replace the affected url fields with, formatted like this:

```
us.test.com test.com
hello.com/se hello.com
...
```

So the end result should be:

```
[
  { ...,
    ...,
    "url": "test.com"
  },
  ...
]
```

Is there a way to do this in Vim or do I need to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'd do this programmatically in Vim ;-) As you'll see it's quite similar to Python and many other scripting languages.

Let's suppose we have json file open. Then

```
:let foo = json_decode(join(getline(1, '$')))
```

will load json into VimScript variable. So `:echo foo` will show `[{'url': 'us.test.com'}, {'url': 'hello.com/se'}]`.

Now let's switch to a "mapping" file. We're going to split all lines and make a Dictionary like that:

```
:let bar = {}
:for line in getline(1, '$') | let field = split(line) | let bar[field[0]] = field[1] | endfor
```

Now `:echo bar` shows `{'hello.com/se': 'hello.com', 'us.test.com': 'test.com'}` as expected.

To perform a substitution we do simply:

```
:for field in foo | let field.url = bar->get(field.url, field.url) | endfor
```

And now `foo` contains `[{'url': 'test.com'}, {'url': 'hello.com'}]` which is what we want. The remaining step is to write the new value into a buffer with

```
:put =json_encode(foo)
```

Comment: How would this work if we also have some fields in the original that do not need substitution (I.E. they are not in the dictionary of changes)?

Comment: @Marc As you can see all other fields are untouched.

Comment: I tried running the command but get an error
```
E731: using Dictionary as a String
E15: Invalid expression: bar->get(field.url,field.url) | endfor
```

Comment: @Marc Is this Neovim? Why no tag then? Try `get(bar, field.url, field.url)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could…

1. turn those lines in your mappings file (`/tmp/mappings` for illustration purpose):

   ```
   us.test.com test.com
   hello.com/se hello.com
   ...
   ```

   into:

   ```
   g/"url"/s@us.test.com@test.com@g
   g/"url"/s@hello.com/se@hello.com@g
   ...
   ```

   with:

   ```
   :%normal Ig/"url"/s@
   :%s/ /@
   ```

   The idea is to turn the file into a script that will perform all those substitutions on all lines matching `"url"`.

   If you are confident that those strings are only in `"url"` lines, you can just do:

   ```
   :%normal I%s@
   :%s/ /@
   ```

   to obtain:

   ```
   %s@us.test.com@test.com@g
   %s@hello.com/se@hello.com@g
   ...
   ```
2. write the file:

   ```
   :w
   ```
3. and source it from your JSON file:

   ```
   :source /tmp/mappings
   ```

See `:help :g`, `:help :s`, `:help :normal`, `:help :range`, `:help :source`, and `:help pattern-delimiter`.